# How can I set window to undefined in order to test the SSR rendering in an isomorphic application?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, isomorphic-javascript

I have been trying to test an else block for when window is undefined.
As I'm using Next.js the window will be undefined during server side rendering (SSR). At present I can not find a way to do this.

Any help is much appreciated.

I have tried setting `window = undefined` and `global.window = undefined` in the test and within the definition before function (both all and each options). Both approaches have not been successful.

When Googling the closest answer I can find is mocking or spying on a window method but this doesn't answer my problem. I have also found people noting you can run the test as a Node application (thus SSR) but not sure how this can be done for one test.

I have provided an example below of what I am trying to test and how.

**Function to Test**

```
export default () => {
   console.log(typeof window); // This is always an object and never undefined
   const language =
      typeof window !== 'undefined'
          ? window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language || 'en'
          : 'en';

   return language;
};
```

**Jest Test**

```
import getLanguage = './getLanguage';

describe('Get Language SSR', () => {
    const realWindow = window;

    beforeAll(() => {
        window = undefined;
    });

    afterAll(() => {
        window = realWindow;
    });

    it('should return "en"', () => {
         expect(getLanguage()).toEqual('en');
    })
});
```

The code coverage shows that the else block is never hit.

Answer (score 4):

["By adding a @jest-environment docblock at the top of the file, you can specify another environment to be used for all tests in that file"](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string):

```
/**
 * @jest-environment node
 */

import getLanguage from './getLanguage';

describe('Get Language SSR', () => {

  it('should return "en"', () => {
    expect(getLanguage()).toEqual('en');  // SUCCESS
  })

});
```

The `@jest-environment` docblock will set the test environment for *this test file* to `node` causing `window` to be `undefined` and resulting in the test passing.