# How to write test case for undefined window Object | Vue test utils | Jest Framework

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I am using vue test utils - Jest framework for unit testing of my vue file. I'm not able to test the below line.

```
const inBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';
```

My question is how to set **JavaScript Window**  as undefined. Is there any way to set window as undefined Browser Object Model (BOM)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set window to undefined in order to test the SSR rendering in an isomorphic application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54038514/how-can-i-set-window-to-undefined-in-order-to-test-the-ssr-rendering-in-an-isomo)

Answer (score -1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919370/jasmine-mock-window-object) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885841/how-to-mock-the-javascript-window-object-using-jest) you can use the [.spyOn](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) function and set the window as undefined:

```
let windowSpy;

beforeEach(() => {
  windowSpy = jest.spyOn(global, 'window', 'get');
  windowSpy.mockImplementation(() => undefined);
});

it('window should be undefined.', () => {
  expect(window).toBeUndefined();
});
```

Comment: I received error like this. can you please help me to sort out this 

` Cannot spyOn the window property; it is not a function
`